# Gson not properly serializing JSON into POJO with Retrofit

Tags: java, json, gson, retrofit

I have the following JSON returning back from the NYTimes TopStories API;

```
{
"status": "OK",
"copyright": "Copyright (c) 2015 The New York Times Company. All Rights Reserved.",
"last_updated": "2015-07-03T01:25:02-05:00",
"num_results": 21,
"results": [
    {
        "section": "World",
        "subsection": "Africa",
        "title": "Tunisia Jihadist Died in Libya Strike, U.S. Official Says",
        "abstract": "Seifallah Ben Hassine, one of Osama bin Laden’s top lieutenants and Tunisia’s most wanted jihadist, was killed in an American airstrike in Libya last month, a senior United States official said.",
        "url": "http://www.nytimes.com/2015/07/03/world/africa/jihadist-from-tunisia-died-in-strike-in-libya-us-official-says.html",
        "byline": "By CARLOTTA GALL and ERIC SCHMITT",
        "item_type": "Article",
        "updated_date": "2015-07-02T21:18:07-5:00",
        "created_date": "2015-07-02T21:18:10-5:00",
        "published_date": "2015-07-03T04:00:00-5:00",
        "material_type_facet": "News",
        "kicker": "",
        "des_facet": [
            "Terrorism",
            "Defense and Military Forces"
        ],
        "org_facet": "",
        "per_facet": [
            "Hassine, Seifallah Ben",
            "bin Laden, Osama"
        ],
        "geo_facet": [
            "Tunisia",
            "Libya"
        ],
        "multimedia": ""
    }
]
}
```

NYTimes returns this `JSON` with a header of `text/json`, I am not sure if that has any effect on this.

I am using Retrofit, and my onSuccess method is never reached in the call back. I have the model classes declared like so:

**Main Model Class**

```
public class TopStories {

    @SerializedName("status")
    private String mStatus;
    public String getStatus() {
        return mStatus;
    }

    @SerializedName("copyright")
    private String mCopyright;
    public String getCopyright() {
        return mCopyright;
    }

    @SerializedName("last_updated")
    private String mLastUpdated;
    public String getLastUpdated() {
        return mLastUpdated;
    }

    @SerializedName("num_results")
    private int mNumResults;
    public int getNumResults() {
        return mNumResults;
    }

    @SerializedName("results")
    private List<Result> mResults;
    public List<Result> getResults() {
        return mResults;
    }

}
```

**Results Model Class**

```
public class Result {

    @SerializedName("section")
    private String mSection;
    public String getSection() {
        return mSection;
    }

    @SerializedName("subsection")
    private String mSubSection;
    public String getSubSection() {
        return mSubSection;
    }

    @SerializedName("title")
    private String mTitle;
    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    @SerializedName("abstract")
    private String mAbstract;
    public String getAbstract() {
        return mAbstract;
    }

    @SerializedName("url")
    private String mUrl;
    public String getUrl() {
        return mUrl;
    }

    @SerializedName("byline")
    private String myByLine;
    public String getMyByLine() {
        return myByLine;
    }

    @SerializedName("item_type")
    private String mItemType;
    public String getItemType() {
        return mItemType;
    }

    @SerializedName("updated_date")
    private String mUpdatedDate;
    public String getUpdatedDate() {
        return mUpdatedDate;
    }

    @SerializedName("created_date")
    private String mCreatedDate;
    public String getCreatedDate() {
        return mCreatedDate;
    }

    @SerializedName("multimedia")
    private List<Multimedia> mMultimedia;
    public List<Multimedia> getMultimedia() {
        return mMultimedia;
    }

}
```

You get the idea, and I have another model class for `"multimedia"`, ok moving on I created a `RestAdapter` like so:

```
private NYTimesService() {

    mAsyncRestAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(API_URL)
            .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                @Override
                public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                    request.addEncodedQueryParam("api-key", API_KEY);
                }
            })
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .build();
}
```

And I have an API Interface like so:

```
public interface ITopStories {

    @Headers("Content-Type: text/json")
    @GET("/topstories/v1/home.json")
    void getTopStories(Callback<TopStories> callback);

}
```

And my `Callback<T>` is defined like so:

```
@Subscribe
public void onLoadTopStories(LoadTopStories loadTopStories) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onLoadTopStories");
    Callback<TopStories> callback = new Callback<TopStories>() {
        @Override
        public void success(TopStories topStories, Response response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess");
            mBus.post(new LoadedTopStories(topStories));
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        }
    };
    sClient.getTopStories(callback);
}
```

The `Log.d(TAG, "onLoadTopStories");` gets called fine, the problem is that `Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess");` is never reached. What is the issue here?

Some Notes:

- "results" can be an array or a string if its empty
- same thing with "multimedia"
- What baffles me is that `.getCopyright()` or `getStatus()` is never serialized to begin with in `TopStories.java`

Also `Retrofit` has no problem with the `GET` request and it initiates it properly:

[image]

**Update**

Added log statements to `onFailure` and I get the following:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 10819 path $.results[4].multimedia

**Multimedia can be an Array or an Empty String**

```
"multimedia": [
            {
                "url": "http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/07/04/world/04Greece1-web/04Greece1-web-thumbStandard.jpg",
                "format": "Standard Thumbnail",
                "height": 75,
                "width": 75,
                "type": "image",
                "subtype": "photo",
                "caption": "A Greek Orthodox priest giving money to a man on a street in Thessaloniki, Greece, on Friday.",
                "copyright": "Giannis Papanikos/Associated Press"
            },
            {
                "url": "http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/07/04/world/04Greece1-web/04Greece1-web-thumbLarge.jpg",
                "format": "thumbLarge",
                "height": 150,
                "width": 150,
                "type": "image",
                "subtype": "photo",
                "caption": "A Greek Orthodox priest giving money to a man on a street in Thessaloniki, Greece, on Friday.",
                "copyright": "Giannis Papanikos/Associated Press"
            },
            {
                "url": "http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/07/04/world/04Greece1-web/04Greece1-web-articleInline.jpg",
                "format": "Normal",
                "height": 127,
                "width": 190,
                "type": "image",
                "subtype": "photo",
                "caption": "A Greek Orthodox priest giving money to a man on a street in Thessaloniki, Greece, on Friday.",
                "copyright": "Giannis Papanikos/Associated Press"
            },
            {
                "url": "http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/07/04/world/04Greece1-web/04Greece1-web-mediumThreeByTwo210.jpg",
                "format": "mediumThreeByTwo210",
                "height": 140,
                "width": 210,
                "type": "image",
                "subtype": "photo",
                "caption": "A Greek Orthodox priest giving money to a man on a street in Thessaloniki, Greece, on Friday.",
                "copyright": "Giannis Papanikos/Associated Press"
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Maybe failure is called?

Comment: Oh yes I forgot to include Log statements in onFailure, updated question.

Comment: Not sure why someone down-voted this, this is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I was able to get this working by creating a custom Deserialization class that extends `Gson`'s `JsonDeserializer<T>` class. The following code worked for me:

```
public class ResultsDeserializerJson implements JsonDeserializer<Result> {

@Override
public Result deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

    JsonElement titleElement = json.getAsJsonObject().get("title");
    JsonElement multimediaElement = json.getAsJsonObject().get("multimedia");
    if (multimediaElement.isJsonArray()) {
        return new Result(
                titleElement.toString(),
                (Multimedia[]) context.deserialize(multimediaElement.getAsJsonArray(), Multimedia[].class));
    } else if (multimediaElement.getAsString().equals("")) {
        Multimedia multimedia = new Multimedia();
        multimedia.setFormat("");
        multimedia.setUrl("");
        return new Result(titleElement.toString(), multimedia);
    } else {
        Log.d("ResultsDeserializerJson", multimediaElement.toString());
        throw new JsonParseException("Unsupported type of multimedia element");
    }
}
}
```

I added the following constructor to `Result.java`:

```
public Result(String title, Multimedia ... multimedia) {
    this.mTitle = title.replace("\"", "");;
    mMultimedia = Arrays.asList(multimedia);
}
```

I still feel like this is somewhat hacky, and there is a better solution. I'll investigate this some more but for now this is working fine. You can add more parameters to the `Multimedia` constructor but this still does not satisfy me fully as an answer in some ways.

This is the result I see now:

[image]

Sourcecode for the application is here: [NYTimes Android App Repo](https://github.com/ZkHaider/SampleNYTimesApp/tree/master)

Answer (score 0):

Your POJO is incorrect,  Multimedia is not a list, it's just a String,  according to your JSON

Comment: Wrong if you read the question "multimedia" returns as either an array or a string.

Comment: Well what I wrote stands, read the error. It's expecting an array to be read in json, but it's getting a String

Comment: Yes that is very obvious, I am writing a solution to this now.